# Issue with logo on Twitter Bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm working on my first website with Twitter Bootstrap. Works great.
Now I'm trying to get the website responsive.
When I make the screen smaller(Too simulate a mobile phone screen), the logo gets bigger and bigger, until it gets too the smallest page size(I geuss?), then it jumps too a smaller size and it stays there.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I want it too stay the same size...
HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="container">
        <img id="logo" class="span2 offset1" src="img/logo.png" title="Hostellerie De Hamert">
        <h1 id="deHamert" class="text-center span6">Hostellerie De Hamert</h1>
    </div>
```

CSS:`#logo{
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: none;
}`

And of course, bootstrap integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the "span2" class on the image element. When using Bootstraps responsive library all "spans" will stack on top of each other instead of float from a certain screen width. I suggest you simply set the width and height of #logo to a static value.

http://jsfiddle.net/pC2xd/

Try removing the `width: 100px; height: 100px` to see what happens without these static values.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try `class='container-fluid'`.

refer here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive